# multiple where query in firestore queryBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I just noticed today that whenever I want to query a database I get an error which doesn't really make a sense to me and querying just stop working. It worked just fine few weeks ago.

> Invalid Query. All where filters with an inequality (lessThan,
>   lessThanOrEqual, greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqual) must be on the
>   same field. But you have inequality filters on 'value1' and 'value2')

```
  Stream<List<MyModel>> myStream(
      {MyFilter filter, String category}) {
    return _service.collectionsStream(
        path: APIPath.tools(cid, category),
        queryBuilder: filter != null
            ? (query) => query
                .where('value1', isGreaterThan: filter.minValue1)
                .where('value1', isLessThan: filter.maxValue1)
                .where('value2', isLessThan: filter.maxValue2)
                .where('value2', isGreaterThan: filter.minValue2)
            : null,
        builder: (data, documentID) => MyModel.fromMap(data, documentID),
        sort: (lhs, rhs) => lhs.value1.compareTo(rhs.value1));
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong? What does that error means and why I didn't get it last time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Firestore query can only contain relational conditions (`>`, `<`, etc) on a single field. From the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> Queries with range filters on different fields are not supported.

So  you'll have to choose which field you want Firestore to perform a range filter on. You'll then have to do the others in your application code.

To learn more about why this limit exists, and on working within Firestore's limitations to implement use-cases, I highly recommend checking out the video series [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: wow... I wish I know that before I chose firestore for my app. Is there any chance to make it work even If I will have to spend week writing it? I mean querying data is the main reason of my app so without it I can start all over again with different database then

Comment: No effort on your part can change the capabilities of this API, so you'll have to learn how to use it. A thing to always keep in mind is that Firestore has a unique, hard performance guarantee, and it will only allow operations for which is can maintain that guarantee. That's why it doesn't allow many query types that you may be able to perform on other databases:

Comment: As said, Firestore's main focus is on its unique performance guarantee. If the query capabilities are more important for your use-case than those performance guarantees,  you may want to look at another solution.

Comment: Do you query on big amounts of data? If yes you have to use another database or use solutions like algolia (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search). If not you can download entires collections and do the filter work in intern. I didn't re-updated my code because if you are dealing with big amounts of data my solution isn't a good practice.

Comment: I never used Algolia, but algolia isn't just for full text search, Algolia is a tool to provide complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

With firebase you can't do a query on multiples fields of a document.
So in your case you can't do a query on 'value1' AND 'value2', you have to do a query on 'value1' and after, filter in intern your query to match 'value2'.

Example:

```
//your query code 
queryBuilder: filter != null
            ? (query) => query             
                .where('value2', isGreaterThan: filter.minValue2)
                .where('value2', isLessThan: filter.maxValue2)
                ...
            : null,
//your query code

myQuery = querySnapshot.documents.where((document) => document.data['value1'] > filter.minValue1).toList();
```